# Efficient Combinatorial Algorithm for Resource Allocation

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization, scheduling

I'm working on a resource allocation problem for a complex project and need help optimizing my algorithm. The problem can be summarized as follows:

I have a set of N tasks, each with a specific duration (in hours), and a set of M resources with varying skill levels. Each task requires one or more resources to complete, and the goal is to minimize the total time required to complete all tasks while ensuring that each task is assigned to resources with appropriate skill levels.

Here's a simplified representation of my current approach:

```
for each permutation of resources:
    for each task in order:
        assign task to the first available resource with the required skill level
```

However, this approach has exponential time complexity and is not practical for my large dataset (N and M can be quite large).

I've looked into various combinatorial optimization techniques, such as the Hungarian algorithm and branch and bound, but I'm struggling to adapt them to this specific resource allocation problem.

I'm looking for guidance on efficient algorithms or libraries (in Python or any other language) that can help me solve this resource allocation problem with a focus on minimizing the total completion time while respecting skill level constraints. Any suggestions or insights into how to approach this problem more efficiently would be greatly appreciated.

Please note that this problem description is simplified for clarity, and I'm open to any advanced optimization techniques or libraries that can significantly improve the efficiency of my solution.

Comment: You have to split and define skill time for each task. Summarized time for the task helps not a lot.

Comment: Do the tasks have to be done in order?

Comment: I do not understand where and what is *time* in all of this. Does skill level affect it? Also, why you make for loop over all permutations of resources. I have trouble understanding your problem.

Comment: could you share some input/output samples? I can help you here